# How to flatten array in Verilog

Tags: arrays, verilog

As Verilog does not allow to pass the array as input to module, so how can we flatten any array in Verilog. Suppose I have this array:

```
parameter [31:0] A [0:31];
wire [31:0] B
```

I want to pass this into any module like:

```
module1 M1 (.input(A), .output (B));
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry about my misunderstading, I am not clear about flatten array. Can you describe it more. 

On the other hand, if you map parameter, it should be `module #(.para(A)) M1 (.output(B));` . I do not think map parameter as InputOutput is legal.

Comment: As my best understand, you should use `generate` to convert `A` to one dimensional array to map.

Comment: @KhanhN.Dang By flattening I mean converting it into 1D. For example I have array {1,2,3,4,5}; I want to pass each member one by one into module. Hope it helps to understand the problem

Comment: I would like to go with the method given below. If I have large array of thousand members then it will be taking a lot of clock cycles... But it would be good to know about array passing on clock for knowledge.

Comment: If you have large array containing thousands elements each of multiple bits you will have a very large bus. It is not likely to fit on an FPGA and closing timing would be very problematic.

Comment: @AwaisHussain : It seem you got the answer but I have to say that if you want to do that in verilog, better you should use 1 dimension array. You can do everything with 1 dimension array instead (I think your code is just a little bit more complex). Second choice is SystemVerilog, unless you have to fix with verilog, system verilog is much more better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This verilog restriction is just a pain in... and etc... but we have to deal with it.

You can map the 2D array onto a 1D array like this :

```
wire [32*32-1:0]One_D_array;
integer i;
for (i=0; i<32; i=i+1) assign One_D_array[32*i+31:32*i] = A[i];
```

Then in your module, you can recreate the 2D array with the inverted for loop :

```
wire [31:0]local_2D_array[0:31];
integer i;
for (i=0;i<32;i=i+1) assign local_2D_array[i] = input[32*i+31:32*i];
```

The synthesis tool will handle it as wire remapping, so no LUT/FLIP_FLOP will be used. This is the easiest workaround I found for this limitation.

Comment: SystemVerilog can have array style ports.

Comment: Indeed. This answer applies for verilog only.

Comment: I am trying to implement 1st part of code that is making 2D into 1D. Here is code:

    module Array_passing_testing(
    input clk
    );
    parameter [31:0] A[0:31]=    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    wire [32*32-1:0]One_D_array;
   genvar i;

   for (i=0; i<7; i=i+1)
   assign #10 One_D_array[32*i-1:32*i] = A[i];
   endmodule
But it is giving following error:
Part-select direction is opposite from prefix index direction.

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting. I tried to edit it but 5 minutes had passed and 4 spaces for codes didn't work

Comment: @AwaisHussain try reversing the bit range instead of `[32*i-1:32*i]` try `[32*i:32*i-1]`.

Comment: `module Array_passing_testing(
    input clk
    );

reg [31:0] A[0:31];

wire [31:0] C;

wire [32*32-1:0]One_D_array;
genvar i;
integer a;

initial begin
  for (a=0; a<32; a=a+1) begin
    A[a]=a;
  end
end
for (i=0; i<7; i=i+1) begin
  assign  #10 One_D_array[32*i:32*i-1] = A[i];
end
endmodule`

   

 One_D_array is Z in simulation. Where I am doing it wrong? Thanks!
I am newbie so I might be asking little annoying questions :)